# Unable to reach hostname(port) during the communication b/w queue managers and while injecting the messages with amqsputc in MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am having two queue managers on my local host named QMA running on port 1414 and QMB on 1415. I have defined SDR-RCVR channel pair on both the queue managers. When I placed the messages on the remote queue, there are ending up in the transmission queue and the SDR channel is going to continuous retry. I have tried to give the Connection name as locat host, hostname of mine, IPaddress and 127.0.0.1. Nevertheless, none is working out. I have defined the SVRCONN Channel on QMB and initialized MQSERVER variable like below: 
QMB.SVRCONN/TCP/AnilReddy-PC(1415). As I said above, I have changed the connection name to making it working, but it's getting aborted with the following error in the error logs:

An error occurred receiving data from 169.254.231.219(1415) over TCP/IP. This
may be due to a communications failure.

hostname is responding to pings, I could see the listener is also running. I am using amqsputc to pace the messages on a queue of QMB.

Please suggest me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance for sparing your time to look into my issue.

Comment: What the error logs for QMA and QMB say?

Comment: Please provide the full details of the error you saw in you AMQERR01.LOG. I can see from the text you provided that you got error AMQ9208. This error message has more information in it than you provided, specifically it will provide a TCP/IP error code in some text like, "The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746')". Please provide this very important information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SDR/RCVR channel configuration from QMB to QMA is not correct or a listener is not defined/running in QMA. You will need have  definitions like this:

In QMA:

```
def chl(TO.QMA) chltype(RCVR)
def listener(LISTENER.TCP2) trptype(TCP) port(2424)
start listener(LISTENER.TCP2)
```

In QMB

```
def ql(QMA) USAGE(XMITQ)
def chl(TO.QMA) chltype(SDR) conname('localhost(2424)') xmitq(QMA)
start channel(TO.QMA)
def qremote(QR.SDLQ) RNAME(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE) RQMNAME(QMA) XMITQ(QMA)
```

Make sure you have the same name for both SDR and RCVR channels.

Comment: Good Evening Sir, 

I made sure, SDR/RCVR channel names are same. 
I have defined new listener and started it. still, issue is recurring. 

 TCP    0.0.0.0:1414           AnilReddy-PC:0         LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1415           AnilReddy-PC:0         LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           AnilReddy-PC:0         LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:2424           AnilReddy-PC:0         LISTENING

Comment: Yes sir, they are configured properly. I would like to highlight few more points in here.

1)If we suspect the problem with listener, I am able to connect to them by using telnet. So I don't think any problem in there. 

2) I am using trigger type depth and when it is 1. Also, a process to run the channel 'runmqchl'. Though transmit queue is having messages, am not seeing any messages on SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ. aren't we suppose to have a trigger message on it?

Comment: It will be very had to see messages on the SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ because they will be consumed almost as soon as they are placed on it, by the channel initiator process. The fact that your channel made an attempt to start and then had the communications failure that you report shows that triggering is not your issue. We need the full data from the error to tell why TCP/IP is unhappy.

Comment: Hello Morag, I am seeing below error too.

6/19/2015 11:22:50 - Process(5328.4) User(Anil Reddy) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                    Host(ANILREDDY-PC)
AMQ6125: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred.

EXPLANATION:
An internal error has occurred with identifier 20809700.  This message is issued in association with other messages.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 5328.